# Connection between two servers using Federated

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel-5, phpmyadmin

I have one database in server A but my application is running in server B

So, in order to separate the information, I used Federated in server B to access the tables from server A. I tried two things:

```
CREATE SERVER s
FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER mysql
OPTIONS (DATABASE 'XPTO', USER 'aaa', PASSWORD 'aaa', HOST 'serverA');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CONNECTION='s';
```

And I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `col1` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`col1`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CONNECTION='mysql://aaa:aaa@IP_ADDRESS:3306/XPTO/test'
```

The problem is that I have a lot of connections. It is one connection foreach table and every time I execute the query again, it creates a new connection. If I have 11 tables, it creates 11 connections, after executing again, I get 11+11 connections = 22 connections, and so on...

After creating this, the problem was still there. 
So I tried to create a view in server B from the tables that I created with the last code and I did the querys at the views only. But the problem still there again!

How can I execute the query and close the connections that are "sleep"?

Comment: That's one of the problems with `FEDERATED`.  You can close them manually by issuing `FLUSH LOCAL TABLE t1;` but I doubt that is the answer you are looking for.  Are the open connections a problem?  Many people seem overly concerned by them, but they are sleeping, not consuming much in the way of resources other than a little bit of memory.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot its a concern because sometimes I get the error when the application tries to connect because there are many connections.

Comment: When you created the view, how did you do that on the client server (the one using `FEDERATED`)?  There's a trick to federating a view -- you don't declare it as a view on the client server.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I created like the following
CREATE VIEW v_cs_type AS
SELECT * FROM database.cs_type;